# Bootstrap Right Sidebar with Affix & Offcanvas

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix, off-canvas-menu

Hello ive been struggling in what seems like years to have a right sidebar both be stuck on larger displays and then go offcanvas on smaller displays. Im nearly there on my test site but i fear that i cant link to it as SE doesnt like links to websites but ive got too much code and ive struggled to make a jsfiddle with it all. i have tried.

Suppose i could just take any pointers that folks could offer. That would be appreciated too. Here is a link to my site (non seo as i dont use the website) to maybe help assist me in where i am going wrong. thanks.
http://kompressaur.com/index.html

Everything works fine till i get to the mobile breakpoint. Then the toggle nav button that appears doesnt want to do anything. All help appreciated as my soul has been destroyed. Its taken me almost 7 years to get this far and look ..its all still pretty poor.

thanks

:(

Comment: You need to post your code in your question, otherwise once the problem is fixed the question has little value. Also, you should start by check your console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I think your best bet is to actually use css position sticky along with the stickyfill polyfill for this because you can then just very simply use css to customize this for mobile and also you don't need to worry about your header size and it will stop for your footer as well.

You can read about css position sticky here https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

So I had a little time on my hands and figured I would put together a little something.  I figured I would just make the whole page so you can copy and paste it to see it working.  I just linked to the cdn's for bootstrap, jquery and the stickyfill polyfill but you can just go to the url and copy them so you can run them on your local server.

Here it is it should look identical to your page with a few differences copy and paste this whole page and see how it works then you can customize to your liking:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{padding-top:50px; overflow-x:hidden;}

#masthead{
  min-height:200px;
  padding:40px 0;
}
footer{
  height:1000px;
  background:#efefef;
  margin-top:40px;
}



@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  #sidebar-wrapper{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 70px;
    /*the following gives a smoother scrooll in webkit broswers*/
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .sidebar-toggle{display:none; }
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  #sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;bottom:20px;right:-90%;left:auto;
    width:90%;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    z-index:99999;
    /*the following gives a smoother scrooll in webkit broswers*/
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .sidebar-open #sidebar{
    right:0;
  }
  .sidebar-open .sidebar-overlay{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:9999;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-toggle{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:none;
    background:#efefef;
    outline:0;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Bootply</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mylinks">Links</button>      
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small</button>  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small</button>       
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small</button>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Get Started</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Visualize</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Prototype</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>


<div id="masthead">  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1>Bootstrap Sidebar
          <p class="lead">With Css Sticky and Off Canvas</p>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="well well-lg"> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/180x100" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              nothing here
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/masthead-->


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sidebar-toggle">Open Sidebar</button>

      <h2 id="sec0">Content</h2>
        <p>
          At Bootply we like to build simple Bootstrap templates that utilize the code Bootstap CSS without a lot of customization. Sure you can 
          find a lot of Bootstrap themes and inspiration, but these templates tend to be heavy on customization.</p>

        <hr>
        <p>
          Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.              
          Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut!</p>

        <h2 id="sec1">Content</h2>
        <p>
          Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut.
        </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Hello.</h3></div>
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
                dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
                Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Hello.</h3></div>
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
                dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
                Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h2 id="sec2">Section 2</h2>
        <p>
          Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut!
        </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <h2 id="sec3">Section 3</h2>
        <p>
          Images are responsive sed @mdo but sum are more fun peratis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
          totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
        </p>
        <p>
          Fos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
        </p>

        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
          totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
        </p>


        <h2 id="sec4">Section 4</h2>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
          totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
        </p>

        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
          totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
          dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores 
          eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, 
          sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
          Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
        </p>


    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-overlay"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
        <button class="sidebar-toggle">Close Sidebar</button>
        <li class="active"><a href="#sec0">Section 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec3">Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec4">Section 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/left-->



  </div>
</div>

<footer></footer>


<!-- JavaScripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickyfill/1.1.4/stickyfill.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sidebar-wrapper').Stickyfill();
});


$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sidebar-wrapper', offset:70});
$('#sidebar a').click(function() {
  if($('body').hasClass("sidebar-open")){
    $('body').removeClass("sidebar-open");
  }
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top- 50
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});

$('.sidebar-toggle, .sidebar-overlay').click(function(){
  $('body').toggleClass("sidebar-open");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

First I used jquery to toggle the class of sidebar-open to the body.  This will allow you to customize the sidebar and overlay when the sidebar-toggle button is clicked.  Then at larger screens you can use position sticky to the sidebar wrapper and that is what will make it follow as you scroll.  Then the polyfill will take care of browsers that don't support css position sticky.

You can find and read about the polyfill here https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill